# Is Ajax to database safe?

Tags: ajax, database

I have a code to update a database with ajax.
I want to know if this is safe to do it?

Also, is it better to use fetch()? And how can I change this code with a fetch()?

Thank you.

```
function save_to_db(cart_id, new_quantity, newPrice) {
    var inputQuantityElement = $("#input-quantity-"+cart_id);
    var priceElement = $("#cart-price-"+cart_id);
    $.ajax({
        url : "update_cart_quantity.php",
        data : "cart_id="+cart_id+"&new_quantity="+new_quantity,
        type : 'post',
        success : function(response) {
            $(inputQuantityElement).val(new_quantity);
            $(priceElement).text("$"+newPrice);
            var totalQuantity = 0;
            $("input[id*='input-quantity-']").each(function() {
                var cart_quantity = $(this).val();
                totalQuantity = parseInt(totalQuantity) + parseInt(cart_quantity);
            });
            $("#total-quantity").text(totalQuantity);
            var totalItemPrice = 0;
            $("div[id*='cart-price-']").each(function() {
                var cart_price = $(this).text().replace("$","");
                totalItemPrice = parseInt(totalItemPrice) + parseInt(cart_price);
            });
            $("#total-price").text(totalItemPrice);
            $("#total-price-foot").text(totalItemPrice);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: the safety/security of your database is not necessarily related to how you update it, but moreso to do with are you using a secure server (https) /how strong are your passwords etc

Comment: I agree with the above comment, and safeness would also encompass whether or not you use transactions correctly or otherwise prevent simultaneous database access.